# Configuring default.deserialization.exception.handler in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Kafka provides the `StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG`  parameter to use a different `DeserializationExceptionHandler` than the default one that simply crashes and burns. I added this parameter to a `ConsumerStrategy` passed to Spark's `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream()`:

```
  kafkaParams.put( StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class );
  consumerStrategy = ConsumerStrategies.<String, byte[]>Subscribe( topicsSet, kafkaParams );
  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream( streamingContext,
                                 LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                                 consumerStrategy );
```

Log files report this warning, and the application still crashes and burns upon receipt of a poison pill message:

> ConsumerConfig: The configuration 'default.deserialization.exception.handler' was supplied but isn't a known config.

It's unclear to me if there are differences between `StreamsConfig` and `ConsumerConfig`.  If there are, I haven't found any way to pass `StreamsConfig` to `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream()`.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated...